# c# accessing hashtable of two-dimensional arrays

Tags: c#

I've created a hashtable of two-dimensional arrays in c# and cannot figure out how to directly access the array values, the following is my current code:

```
// create the hashtable
Hashtable hashLocOne = new Hashtable();

// add to the hashtable if we don't yet have this location
if (!hashLocOne.ContainsKey(strCurrentLocationId))
  hashLocOne.Add(strCurrentLocationId,new double[20, 2] { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } });

// add to the value at a given array position, this does not work
hashLocAll[strReportLocationId][iPNLLine, 0] += pnl_value;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Hashtable doesn't know what kind of objects are stored in it; you have to manually cast each one:

```
double result = ((double[,]) table["foo"])[4][5];
```

You should use a Dictionary instead of a Hashtable if possible:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<String, double[,]>();
double result = dict["foo"][4][5];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
((double[,])hashLocAll[strReportLocationId])[iPNLLine, 0] += pnl_value;
```

Why dont you use Dictionary<string, double[,]> ?

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a hashtable. You now want to get at that information.

It looks like hashLoc**All** should be hashLoc**One**. However, I'm guessing you have a reason for that.

With hashtables, everything inside is of type "object". Which means you have to do alot of casting.

Try this:

```
((double[,])hashLocOne[strReportLocationId])[iPNLLine, 0] += pnl_value;
```

Answer (score -2):

- I don't see any definitions for `hashLocAll` or `strReportLocationId` in your sample code.
- You are using a non-generic dictionary. Use a generic dictionary instead.
- You are using a bastardized version of Hungarian Notation. Don't do that. Get rid of the prefixes `hash`, `str`, `i`, etc. They are completely unnecessary in a language like C# and only make your code more difficult to read.

Comment: This really doesn't help answer the question, and your last two points make me wish you could delete answers as "subjective and argumentative".